# Question about accessing key value pairs in Python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Beginner here,

How would one go about tracing this code? The dictionary inside a dictionary is throwing me off.
Thank you.

```
mixedKeys = {1:{'three':3, 0:'zeroval'}, 0:'zero', 'two':2}
print(mixedKeys[1][0])
```

Comment: What is throwing you off?  A key can be any data type and a value can be any data type.  This "example" merely demonstrates that.

Comment: @TomServo A key can be any *hashable* data type.

Comment: First, `mixedKeys[1]` gets evaluated. It evaluates to `{'three':3, 0:'zeroval'}`, then `[0]` gets applied to that, which results in `'zeroval'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's take a look

given:

```
mixedKeys = {
    1: {'three':3, 0:'zeroval'}
    0:'zero', 
    'two': 2
}
```

```
mixedKeys[1][0]
```

lets break down `mixedKeys[1][0]`

if we call `mixedKeys[1]` we will get the value which is a dictionary `{'three':3, 0:'zeroval'}`. finally, we are then calling `[0]` (key 0) from that dictionary which results in:

```
zeroval
```